# Best apps for motel booking while road tripping in the US

Tags: usa, bookings, applications, road-trips

I'm planning to do a road trip in the US (West Coast mostly), and I don't want to book my accommodation in advance, in order to be flexible.
What are the best apps for booking motels for the same day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used HotWire for most of my trip, it was cheaper then booking and reliable.

Comment: Can you add a link to HotWire?
Why is it better than other apps?

Comment: https://www.hotwire.com/, I didn't argue that it is better then other apps, I only claim it was cheaper then booking, and it was reliable, I didn't had any trouble using the app.

Answer (score 2):

I am not affiliated with the service, but I recommend [booking.com](http://booking.com) which offers an app and on the day search. You can also sort at the side to search only for motels.